# How to grab only first part of the char?

Tags: javascript

I want to grab only bold text from this char: example.com/en/en/some-text/test%C5%84sk/**thispartofcharIwant**-thisnot-not/not

I have created:

```
const myArr = str.split("/")[5];
```

but it's return me:

```
thispartofcharIwant-thisnot-not/not
```

so that is not my goal, the goal is to get this:

```
thispartofcharIwant
```

Comment: why not split again, this time at '-' and take the first part?

Comment: If splitting it again (as recommended above) doesn't get you what you want in every situation you could get very specific with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let str = 'example.com/en/en/some-text/test%C5%84sk/thispartofcharIwant-thisnot-not/not'

const part = str.split("/")[5].split("-")[0]

// const [part] = str.split("/")[5].split("-"); //alternative way using destructuring

console.log(part)  // 'thispartofcharIwant'
```

Comment: If you already know it's at index `0`, why are you not destructuring?

Comment: @connexo fair question. Destructuring is a great way if you want to access various values of a variable. In this case it's just one, what would be the advantage/improvement/gain? It's one character less (the 0), but the 'logic' is then left and right. For a beginner it might be much harder to read/understand and the other syntax is used with the .split() before. So I'd personally would stick with my solution... but I will add it to the answer anyway, since it's defenitely good having in mind for other cases. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is splitting again and destructuring the resulting array:

```js
const haystack = "example.com/en/en/some-text/test%C5%84sk/thispartofcharIwant-thisnot-not/not";

const [needle] = haystack.split("/")[5].split("-");

console.log(needle);
```